# How do I create new columns containing lead values generated from another column in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

The following code pulls down daily oil prices (dcoilwtico), resamples the daily figures to monthly, calculates the 12-month (i.e. year over year percent) change and finally contains a loop to shift the YoY percent change ahead 1 month (dcoilwtico_1), 2 months (dcoilwtico_2) all the way out to 12 months (dcoilwtico_12) as new columns:

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr

start = datetime.datetime (2016, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime (2022, 12, 1)

#1. Get historic data
df_fred_daily = pdr.DataReader(['DCOILWTICO'],'fred', start, end).dropna().resample('M').mean() # Pull daily, remove NaN and collapse from daily to monthly
df_fred_daily.columns= df_fred_daily.columns.str.lower()   

#2. Expand df range: index, column names
index_fred = pd.date_range('2022-12-31', periods=13, freq='M')
columns_fred_daily = df_fred_daily.columns.to_list()                   

#3. Append history + empty df 
df_fred_daily_forecast = pd.DataFrame(index=index_fred, columns=columns_fred_daily)
df_fred_test_daily=pd.concat([df_fred_daily, df_fred_daily_forecast])

#4. New df, calculate yoy percent change for each commodity 
df_fred_test_daily_yoy= ((df_fred_test_daily - df_fred_test_daily.shift(12))/df_fred_test_daily.shift(12))*100

#5. Extend each variable as a series from 1 to 12 months
for col in df_fred_test_daily_yoy.columns:
   for i in range(1,13):
      df_fred_test_daily_yoy["%s_%s"%(col,i)] = df_fred_test_daily_yoy[col].shift(i)
      
df_fred_test_daily_yoy.tail(18)
```

And produces the following df:
[image]

Question: My real world example contains hundreds of columns and I would like to generate these same results using Pyspark.

How would this be coded using Pyspark?

Comment: there are too many questions you're asking -- could you please boil it down for better reception and understanding? afaiu, you want your pandas code to be written in pyspark -- do you have a starting point on it?

Answer (score 0):

As your code is already ready, I would use koalas, "a pandas spark version", You just need to install https://pypi.org/project/koalas/

see the simple example

```
import databricks.koalas as ks
import pandas as pd

pdf = pd.DataFrame({'x':range(3), 'y':['a','b','b'], 'z':['a','b','b']})

# Create a Koalas DataFrame from pandas DataFrame
df = ks.from_pandas(pdf)

# Rename the columns
df.columns = ['x', 'y', 'z1']

# Do some operations in place:
df['x2'] = df.x * df.x
```